# Easiest way to create a Regex with multiple scenario

Tags: c#, regex

I have function where I have 4 Regex scenario for search tire width..

```
string sizeWidthRgx = @"(\d{3})[\s\/]\d{2}[\s\/R]?[\s\/]\d{2}";
string sizeWidthRgxSecond = @"(\d{3})[\s\/ZR]?\s?\d{2}";
string sizeWidthRgxThird = @"(\d{2})\s?X?x?\s?\d{1,2}[,.]\d{2}";
string sizeWidthRgxFourth = @"(\d{3})[\s\/]\d{2}[\s\/]?R\d{2}";

var matchSizeWidth = Regex.Match(sizeWidthUpper, sizeWidthRgx);
var matchSizeWidthOther = Regex.Match(sizeWidthUpper, sizeWidthRgxSecond);
var matchSizeWidthThird = Regex.Match(sizeWidthUpper, sizeWidthRgxThird);
var matchSizeWidthFourth = Regex.Match(sizeWidthUpper, sizeWidthRgxFourth);
```

Someone have idea how i can join this all regex to one or other way to search this parametr.

For example:

```
(7.50)/80 R16, (305)/35 R24, (31)X10.50R15, (175)/65/14.
```

Thats all scenario i need to take all number from '()'

@Edit
Here is my code:

```
            var sizeWidthUpper = productName.Trim().ToUpper();

        string sizeWidthRgx = @"(\d{3})[\s\/]\d{2}[\s\/R]?[\s\/]\d{2}"; // 1 scenariusz
        string sizeWidthRgxSecond = @"(\d{3})[\s\/ZR]?\s?\d{2}"; // 2 scenariusz
        string sizeWidthRgxThird = @"(\d{2})\s?X?x?\s?\d{1,2}[,.]\d{2}"; //3 scenariusz, np. BARUM BRAVURIS 4X4 31X10.50R15 109 S FR
        string sizeWidthRgxFourth = @"(\d{3})[\s\/]\d{2}[\s\/]?R\d{2}";

        var matchSizeWidth = Regex.Match(sizeWidthUpper, sizeWidthRgx);
        var matchSizeWidthOther = Regex.Match(sizeWidthUpper, sizeWidthRgxSecond);
        var matchSizeWidthThird = Regex.Match(sizeWidthUpper, sizeWidthRgxThird);
        var matchSizeWidthFourth = Regex.Match(sizeWidthUpper, sizeWidthRgxFourth);

        int outSizeWidth = 0;
        if(matchSizeWidth.Success)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(matchSizeWidth.Groups[1].Value, out outSizeWidth))
            {
                if ((outSizeWidth >= 125) && (outSizeWidth <= 335))
                {
                    if ((outSizeWidth % 5) == 0) return outSizeWidth.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        if (matchSizeWidthFourth.Success)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(matchSizeWidthFourth.Groups[1].Value, out outSizeWidth))
            {
                if ((outSizeWidth >= 125) && (outSizeWidth <= 335))
                {
                    if ((outSizeWidth % 5) == 0) return outSizeWidth.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        if(matchSizeWidthOther.Success)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(matchSizeWidthOther.Groups[1].Value, out outSizeWidth))
            {
                if ((outSizeWidth >= 125) && (outSizeWidth <= 335))
                {
                    if ((outSizeWidth % 5) == 0) return outSizeWidth.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        if(matchSizeWidthThird.Success)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(matchSizeWidthThird.Groups[1].Value, out outSizeWidth))
            {
                if ((outSizeWidth >= 30) && (outSizeWidth <= 37)) return outSizeWidth.ToString();
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
```

It works but I need to know can I shorten this code?

Comment: Does your regex flavor support named groups?  Is this c#?

Comment: Yes It's c#. Named groups, really I don't know, but I think c# support this

Comment: Try `var res = Regex.Matches("(7.50)/80 R16, (305)/35 R24, (31)X10.50R15, (175)/65/14", @"\((?<mynum>\d*\.?\d+)\)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["mynum"].Value).ToList();`. One liner, actually. Let me know if you prefer my answer, I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap each pattern in a named group (`(?<name>...)`), for instance:

```
string sizeWidthRgx = @"(?<width>(\d{3})[\s\/]\d{2}[\s\/R]?[\s\/]\d{2})";
```

Make sure that you assign a unique name to each sub-pattern.  Then you can combine them all into one pattern separating them with *or* pipes:

```
IEnumerable<Match> matches = Regex.Matches(sizeWidthUpper, sizeWidthRgx + "|" + sizeWidthRgxSecond + "|" + sizeWidthRgxThird + "|" + sizeWidthRgxFourth);
```

Then you can loop through the matches and look to see if the named group exists in each of the matches (given that pattern, each match will only contain one group):

```
string matchSizeWidth = null;
string matchSizeWidthOther = null;
string matchSizeWidthThird = null;
string matchSizeWidthFourth = null;
foreach(Match m in matches)
    {
    Group g = m.Groups("width");
    if(g.Success) matchSizeWidth = g.Value; 
    g = m.Groups("other");
    if(g.Success) matchSizeWidthOther = g.Value; 
    g = m.Groups("third");
    if(g.Success) matchSizeWidthThird = g.Value; 
    g = m.Groups("fourth");
    if(g.Success) matchSizeWidthFourth = g.Value; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your point:

> Thats all scenario i need to take all number from '()'

You can just use this regex as well:

```
\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/dL5s8dIxTH)

To combine all regexes you can use `|` token which works as an OR condition:

```
regexpattern1|regexpattern2|regexpattern3
```

Comment: That bracket is only for example, what parameter I need to get

Comment: So you mean it returns unwanted result ? and what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You could likely combine the patterns you've got into:

```
\(([0-9.]+)\)[X\/]([0-9.]+)[R\/\s]+([0-9]+)
```

This divides each numerical value into a group, which will then result in three groups.

**Results**:

```
7.50/80 R16
305/35 R24
31/10.50 R15
175/65 R14
```

**Code**:

```
string s = "(7.50)/80 R16, (305)/35 R24, (31)X10.50R15, (175)/65/14.";
string p = "\\(([0-9.]+)\\)[X\\/]([0-9.]+)[R\\/\\s]+([0-9]+)";

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(s, p);
    foreach (Match m in mc) {
       Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1} R{2}", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3]);
    }
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/bF1rH0/1